# How to link different style sheets for different php include files

Tags: php, html, css, include, stylesheet

So I'm dividing my index.php page into three sections:  top, middle, bottom.  The middle section will have different html php inlude pages and therefore will require different style sheets.  Do I link the specific stylesheets in the individual php include pages, or in the index page?  Because in the index page, the different style sheets don't seem to take effect, why is that?

Comment: You're supposed to put the URL to the stylesheet in a variable for your template engine to use appropriately.

Comment: I guess my question was, why don't the stylesheets for the middle section php include files get recognized when i link them in the index.php page?

Comment: We'll need to see code to answer that.

Comment: why cant you use one stylesheet? as stylesheet is set in the head of the html

Comment: You're almost better off creating a single CSS file containing all variants, compressing it (as much as possible - Google for online tools for same) and then include the HTML in the headers for all the pages for that file. The single file may be larger, but on the bright side, it should cache in the browser and overall reduce the bandwidth loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say your `about` page has a custom css file it needs you could do something like this:

about.php

```
<?
$css = array('path_to_css_file', 'path_to_another_css_file');
require_once('header.php'); // aka the top
?>

[about page content goes here]

<?
require_once('footer.php'); // aka the bottom
?>
```

The in your `header.php` file you could do this:

header.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main_style_sheet.css" />
<?
if (isset($css) && is_array($css))
  foreach ($css as $path)
    printf('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="%s" />', $path);
?>
</head>
<body>
```

This way you only load what you need for the given page.